# How to change photo in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to change a photo in flutter? Well, that is, change its brightness, contrast, and so on. I want to do everything the same as on Telegram or Instagram. Please tell me, is it possible to implement this in Flutter, do you mean in Dart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve those tasks using these packages :

1. [image](https://pub.dev/packages/image)
2. [extended_image](https://pub.dev/packages/extended_image)